# not able to access my app running in container using http://localhost:8080/getAll

Tags: docker

I have a spring boot app where i have exposed a web-service '/getAll' which gets records from the database

This is my dockerFile

```
FROM openjdk:8
LABEL maintainer="xxxx"
ADD chinmayee.jar assembly.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-Dspring.profiles.active=container","-jar","/assembly.jar"]
```

---

This is the application.yml

```
 spring:
      profiles: container
      datasource:
        url: jdbc:mysql://${DATABASE_HOST}:${DATABASE_PORT}/${DATABASE_NAME}
        username: ${DATABASE_USER}
        password: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
        initialize: true
        tomcat:
          max-active: 1
      jpa:
        database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

---

I use these commands to bring up the containers

```
docker run -d \
    --name demo-mysql \
    -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root \
    -e MYSQL_DATABASE=chinmayee \
    -e MYSQL_USER=scott \
    -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=tiger \
    mysql:latest

docker run -d \
    --name spring-boot-app \
    --link demo-mysql:mysql \
    -p 8080:8080 \
    -e DATABASE_HOST=demo-mysql \
    -e DATABASE_PORT=3306 \
    -e DATABASE_NAME=chinmayee \
    -e DATABASE_USER=scott \
    -e DATABASE_PASSWORD=tiger \
    chinmayee/chinmayee
```

---

The containers are up, but i get 404 on http://localhost:8080/getAll

Am i missing something?

Comment: please remove -d flag to see logs

Comment: I saw the logs, no errors

Comment: Check with `docker ps -a` that your containers are up and running. Also, `docker inspect ...` your srping-boot-app container to find its IP address and try to access it directly by `http://[container-ip]:8080`. Last thing, what platform do you use, Windows, Mac, Linux? The networking part is different in each case.

Comment: containers are up.

Comment: got the container id of my app using : sudo docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' <CONTAINER ID>. Tried http://<container ip>:8080/getAll>.   Same issue

Comment: Sometimes ports are being allocated so please map your container port to 8090 and try.

Answer (score 0):

The REST api of your application  probably doesn't have a `/getAll` endpoint.

That's why the response you get is a **404 Not Found**. The server is up but can't find what was requested.

> ## [HTTP 404](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404)
>
> The **HTTP 404**, **404 Not Found** and **404** error message is a [Hypertext Transfer Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) (HTTP) [standard response code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes), in computer network communications, to indicate that the client **was able to communicate** with a given server, **but the server could not find what was requested**.
>
> The website hosting server will typically generate a "404 Not Found" web page when a user attempts to follow a broken or dead link.